# How to return data from activity to Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have written Cordova plugin to call a Cordova activity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(cordova.getActivity() , AndroidCamera.class);
cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

I want to return some data from this Android camera activity to my plugin so I can send back it to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

call your activity in Activity for result,

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "*****  result from camera" + requestCode + " *****  " + resultCode);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                     callbackContext.success(base64Image);
              }
        }
```

I am converting Bitmap into Base64 image and sending to server via success method.
It's working perfectly

Comment: How to you pass callBackContext?

Answer (score 0):

See the [Android platform guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins) on Cordova documentation. There is nice example that echos the message back.

```
callbackContext.success(message);
```

where callbackContext is the CallbackContext provided as parameter for *execute* of your plugin.

Also if you want to indicate that error happened, you can call

```
callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
```

Answer (score 0):

### All CordovaPlugin comes with Callback by default

If you are making a CordovaPlugin you extends `CordovaPlugin` class. `CordovaPlugin` class comes with `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)` method which you can override in your plugin to get result.

> Here is a generic Code Sample

```
public class MyCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin{

     private int MY_REQ_CODE = 1000;

     public void someMethod(){
          Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
          cordova.getActivity()startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, MY_REQ_CODE);
     }

    
     @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

       if (requestCode == MY_REQ_CODE) {
           // Do you thing with Data
           log.d("MY_TAG", data);
        
       }
    }

}
```